# Change a color code to another using JavaScript in browser console

Tags: javascript, css, browser, colors, browser-console

I am a web designer.

When I browse web sites I like to change some colors and look at how site will appear when I change the primary color.

I do this using "inspect elements". But it is very time consuming work since I need to add lot of codes to change everywhere.

Is there any JavaScript code which I can use to change one color code to another color code using browser console.

Basically what I want to is something like below...

**Change #FFF8DC color to #e6dfc6 color everywhere in this site using browser console.**

Comment: Probably not. But I haven't done an exhaustive search of the features of all browsers out there.

Comment: of course ... iterate every single element - of each element get the computed style ... go through all those attributes to look for the source colour, you *may* need to look for any or all of `#fff8dc` or `rgb(255,248,220)` or `rgba(255,248,220, \d+)` (\d+ means any number) - then change that to your destination colour - should be about a dozen lines of code

Comment: ^ not to forget `hsla` as well. (and you might want to consider `#ffd` to `#edc` as well?)

Comment: Actually getComputedStyle should always return computed values in the format `"rgb(nnn, nnn, nnn)"` or `rgba(nnn, nnn, nnn, n)` and the whole thing can be reduced to less than a dozen lines: `switchColor=(c1, c2) => {
[...document.all].forEach(e=>{
let s = getComputedStyle(e);
[...s].forEach(k=>{if(s[k]===c1)e.style[k]=c2})
})
};` testable in this very page with `switchColor("rgb(0, 119, 204)", 'pink')`

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson would you like to write a feedback to my answer below, please.

Answer (score 6):

**Principle**

As Kaiido commented: *“ [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) should always return computed values in the format `rgb(nnn, nnn, nnn)` or `rgba(nnn, nnn, nnn, n)`”*.

So, after looping through all the elements computed styles properties, and replace the applicable color values, there *shouldn't* be much to do.

**My updates**

- As you want to be able to *“Change #FFF8DC color to #e6dfc6 color”*, I modified the function from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/5061000) ([RGB to hex and hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)) to be able to use it in my snippet,
- Modified my function to make it work with properties values containing multiple colors (e.g. a gradient),
- Added `strict` as an optional parameter, to be able to avoid the color replacement in values containing multiple colors.

**Snippet**

```js
// Below function modified from solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb
function hexToRgb(hex) {
  // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });

  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? "rgb(" + [
    parseInt(result[1], 16),
    parseInt(result[2], 16),
    parseInt(result[3], 16)
  ].join(', ') + ")" : null;
}

// Function to change a color to another one
function colorChange(colorOld, colorNew, strict = false) {
  // If hex notation, convert to rgb
  if (colorOld.includes('#'))
    colorOld = hexToRgb(colorOld);
  // Loop through all elements styles
  [...document.all].forEach(elm => {
    let cStyle = getComputedStyle(elm);
    [...cStyle].forEach(prop => {
      // Escape if not a string
      if (typeof cStyle[prop] !== 'string') return;
      // Check if colorOld is in property
      if (cStyle[prop].includes(colorOld)){
        // If strict, colorOld is replaced only if it's the only value of the property
        if (!strict || cStyle[prop] === colorOld)
          elm.style[prop] = cStyle[prop].replace(colorOld, colorNew); // Replace color
      }
    })
  })
};

// Then, call your function the way you like !
colorChange("rgb(255, 0, 0)", 'orange');
colorChange("#00ff00", '#125689', true); // Note the use of the “strict” parameter here
colorChange("#00f", 'rgb(255, 0, 128)');
```

```html
<p style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">I was red !</p>
<p style="color: #00ff00;">I was green !</p>
<p style="color: #00f;">I was blue !</p>
<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #0000ff);">
  <p>I was a gradient from red to blue</p>
</div>
<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0f0);">
  <p>I was a gradient from red to green (green is not replaced here, because of the use of “strict”)</p>
</div>
```

Of course, you can try the functions on this very page after copy/pasting those in your console. (for example `colorChange("#eff0f1", "#ffaaaa");`)

Comment: Ah beware, you are assuming you'll retrieve a string from `cStyle[prop]` while it may not be (it is undefined on my FF for Android on I don't know which property...). Edit: could log it, and it is some -moz-window... props and some css variables probably inserted by snippet's console.

Comment: @Kaiido What about I correct it that way: `let cProp = cStyle[prop] || ''` and then use this variable ?

Comment: Since you are not trying to golf anything, I'd rather play safety and readability. You are going to use a String method (`includes`), so check that what you have is indeed a string. You never know what CSS specs will become in a few years, and if they start accepting other types (like number), you'll be glad of this little `if(typeof cStyle[prop] !== 'string') return;`.

Answer (score 0):

> **You wrote:** *Change `#FFF8DC` color to `#e6dfc6` color everywhere in this site using browser console.*

This is very easy! On this site we have `#FFF8DC` as `backgroundColor` by `"Featured on Meta"` `div` block on the right.  You have to put in the browser console:

```
document.querySelector('.community-bulletin').style.backgroundColor = "#e6dfc6";
```

Or you could choose some element using "inspect elements" like on this screenshot:

[image]

and then for changing of this foreground and background colors you have to put in the browser console:

```
$0.style.color = "orange";
$0.style.backgroundColor = "#e6dfc6";
```

press the `enter key` and colors will be changed.

**If you want to use some code for the console all the time** then you have to use snippets. Go to the developer tools and click there on the tab `"Sources"` like on this screenshot:

[image]

then put your code to a new snippet and then click with right mouse button the name from this snippet and in context menu click on `"Run"`. This snippet will be executed. Do not forget to save this snippet: click with right mouse button the name from this snippet and in context menu click on `"Save..."`, but on displayed `"Save dialog box"` click on `"Cancel"` (this is weird) and your snippet will be saved.